# How to dynamically select pre-defined variables in a JS for-if loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object that contains Forex trades each with the following `key:values`

```
[...]
orderType: 0
orderLots: "1.00"
orderSymbol: "AUDCAD"
[...]
```

I now want to define a loop that iterates over each object and returns both the traded short and long volume for the major currencies `(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)`.

- Each trade consists of a base currency `in the example given: AUD` and a counter currency `in the example given: CAD`
- Each trade is either long (orderTypes `0, 2, 4`) or short (orderTypes `1, 3, 5`)
- Each trade has a trade volume expressed in `orderLots` where 1.00 equals 100.000 traded units

Now the idea for the loop is as follows:

- Check if it is  a currency pair that contains two major currencies (e.g. `EURUSD, AUDCAD, etc.`)
- If so, calculate the traded volume for the base **and** counter currency
- If not, calculate the traded volume either for the base or counter currency, depending on which one is the major

My issue (see at the bottom of the code snippet) is that I don't know how to pick the pre-defined variables dynamically as needed. Otherwise I will have to set up dozens of `else if` statements.

```
// define variables
var eurVolumeBought = 0
var eurVolumeSold = 0
var usdVolumeBought = 0
var usdVolumeSold = 0
[...]
var chfVolumeBought = 0
var chfVolumeSold = 0

// iterate each trade in returned JSON object 
for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {

    symbol = trades[i].fields.orderSymbol
    // returns e.g. AUD/CAD

    symbolBase = symbol.slice(0, 3)
    // returns e.g. AUD

    symbolCounter = symbol.slice(3, 6)
    // returns e.g. CAD

    lots = trades[i].fields.orderLots
    // returns e.g. 1.00

    orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType
    // orderTypes 0, 2, 4 are long trades and 1, 3, 5 are short trades accordingly

    // check for main pairs where that contain two major currencies
    if (symbolBase.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/) && symbolCounter.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/){

        // Create logic for long trades
        if (orderType == '0' || orderType == '2' || orderType == '4') {


        // >>>> here i run into issues <<<<
        // In the example given, we have a AUDCAD long trade of 100.000 units.
        // Thus, I want to dynamically pick the audVolumeBought and cadVolumeSold variables 
        // to increase them accordingly. My foolish approach right now is as follows:

        symbolBase = symbolBase.toLowerCase()
        (symbolBase + 'volumeBought') = lots * 100.000 // I try to grab audVolumeBought variable here
        }

}
```

**Edit to @kastenbutts comment:**

The resulting variable's values will be pushed in a chart.JS chart.
So for each trade object there will be either one or two calculations and that's it.

Using

```
result[symbolBase + 'volumeBought'] = result[symbolBase + 'volumeBought'] + (lots * 100.000)
```

returns `NaN`

Comment: The solution depends on how you need the data to be structured for the steps that come after the loop. You could, for example, have a result-Object where each key corresponds to a currency. Then you could say: `result[symbolBase + 'volumeBought'] =  lots * 100.000`

Comment: I know this might be pedantic, but `orderType: 0` is not valid JSON. Do you mean JS object instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox well it is a SQL returned object serialized into JSON. `orderType: 0` represents an integer which in that case doesn't make much sense, I might change it into a string field anytime soon. However, this is not related to my issue :D

Comment: @Phanti you're serialising the object so my comment didn't matter. Fair enough.

Comment: @kastenbutt maybe you can expand a bit on your reply and post an answer. I think this will be a nice solution.

Comment: regarding your edit to kastenbutts, you are doing it wrong. If you look at _his_ code, he initializes the variable the first time (to a number). In you case, you are not (you basically do xx = undefined + 5, which is NaN)

Comment: @grodzi Now I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step you could collect all trades for each currency in an object:

```
let result = {}; // Each key in this object will correspond to a currency

for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {

    symbol = trades[i].fields.orderSymbol
    symbolBase = symbol.slice(0, 3)
    symbolCounter = symbol.slice(3, 6)
    lots = trades[i].fields.orderLots

    orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType

    if (symbolBase.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/) && symbolCounter.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/){

        if (orderType == '0' || orderType == '2' || orderType == '4') {

            symbolBase = symbolBase.toLowerCase()

            if(result.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'volumeBought')) {
                result[symbolBase + 'volumeBought'] += lots * 100.000
            }
            else {
                result[symbolBase + 'volumeBought'] = lots * 100.000
            }

        }
    // ... handle short case 

}
```

As a next step you need to transform the data into a chart object as required by ChartJs. If you want a simple bar chart you would do it like this:

```
let data = [];
let label = [];
for(let cur in result) {
    label.push(cur);
    data.push(result[cur]);
}
let barChart = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            data: data
        }]
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if that exactly fits the logic you require. But it might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. I will try to implement it accordingly and build upon it. What does `hasOwnProperty` stand for?

Comment: See: [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
For these kind of questions you should really use a search engine first. HTML/CSS, Javascript are pretty well documented by Mozilla and others. Don't be afraid to read these references. They often contain examples and you can find answer to a lot of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with just three `if` expressions:

```js
var ma=['EUR','GBP','AUD','CHF','JPY','USD','CAD'];
var volumeBought={}, volumeSold={};
var jo=[
  {fields:{orderType: 0,orderLots: "1.00",orderSymbol: "AUDCAD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 1,orderLots: "0.80",orderSymbol: "USDEUR"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 2,orderLots: "1.40",orderSymbol: "EURAUD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 3,orderLots: "2.20",orderSymbol: "AUDCAD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 4,orderLots: "1.10",orderSymbol: "CADDKK"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 5,orderLots: "1.30",orderSymbol: "GBPUSD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 0,orderLots: "3.04",orderSymbol: "DKKCAD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 1,orderLots: "1.10",orderSymbol: "USDCHF"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 2,orderLots: "0.90",orderSymbol: "JPYEUR"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 3,orderLots: "0.40",orderSymbol: "AUDJPY"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 4,orderLots: "2.30",orderSymbol: "CHFGBP"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 5,orderLots: "3.10",orderSymbol: "EURUSD"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 0,orderLots: "4.25",orderSymbol: "AUDNGN"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 1,orderLots: "0.60",orderSymbol: "USDGBP"}},
  {fields:{orderType: 2,orderLots: "1.70",orderSymbol: "GBPEUR"}}
];

jo.forEach(({fields})=>{
  if (!(fields.orderType%2)) {
  var sld=fields.orderSymbol.substr(0,3),
      bgt=fields.orderSymbol.substr(3,6),
      lots=fields.orderLots*100000;
      if (ma.indexOf(sld)>-1)volumeSold[sld]=(volumeSold[sld]||0) + lots
      if (ma.indexOf(bgt)>-1)volumeBought[bgt]=(volumeBought[bgt]||0) + lots    
  }   
});
console.log('sold:',JSON.stringify(volumeSold))
console.log('bought:',JSON.stringify(volumeBought))
```

Most of the above code deals with generating some sample data. The actual work happens in just a few lines at the bottom. I collect the "sold" and "bought" quantities whenever the given conditions ("long trade" and "major currency") are fulfilled. The result is displayed as a JSON string, but it really is available as a JS object which of course can be used in many different ways.

The expression `volumeSold[sld]=(volumeSold[sld]||0) + lots` will add the value of `lots` to the object's property, regardless of whether it existed before or not (in that case it is initialised with "0" first).

Comment: This is so cool. Will look into it. Interesting to see quiet different solutions for the very same problem all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a working solution. For the sake of completeness, find it below:

```
let resultBought = {}
let resultSold = {}

for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {

symbol = trades[i].fields.orderSymbol
// returns e.g. EUR/USD

symbolBase = symbol.slice(0, 3)
// returns e.g. EUR

symbolCounter = symbol.slice(3, 6)
// returns e.g. USD

lots = trades[i].fields.orderLots
// returns e.g. 1.00

orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType
// orderTypes 0, 2, 4 are long trades, 1, 3, 5 shorts accordingly

// check for major pairs where XXX/YYY = defined currencies
if (symbolBase.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/) && symbolCounter.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/)) {
    // Long Trades Major Pairs
    if (orderType == '0' || orderType == '2' || orderType == '4') {

        // Base currency
        if(resultBought.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'VolumeBought')) {
            resultBought[symbolBase + 'VolumeBought'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultBought[symbolBase + 'VolumeBought'] = lots * 100.000
        }
        // Counter currency
        if(resultSold.hasOwnProperty(symbolCounter + 'VolumeSold')) {
            resultSold[symbolCounter + 'VolumeSold'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultSold[symbolCounter + 'VolumeSold'] = lots * 100.000
        }

    // Short Trades Major Pairs
    } else if (orderType == '1' || orderType == '3' || orderType == '5') {

        // Base currency
        if(resultSold.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'VolumeSold')) {
            resultSold[symbolBase + 'VolumeSold'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultSold[symbolBase + 'VolumeSold'] = lots * 100.000
        }

        // Counter currency
        if(resultBought.hasOwnProperty(symbolCounter + 'VolumeBought')) {
            resultBought[symbolCounter + 'VolumeBought'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultBought[symbolCounter + 'VolumeBought'] = lots * 100.000
        }
      }
// consider the non major pairs
} else if (symbolBase.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/) || symbolCounter.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/)) {
    if (orderType == '0' || orderType == '2' || orderType == '4') {

        if(resultBought.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'VolumeBought')) {
            resultBought[symbolBase + 'VolumeBought'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultBought[symbolBase + 'VolumeBought'] = lots * 100.000
        }

    } else if (orderType == '1' || orderType == '3' || orderType == '5') {

        if(resultSold.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'VolumeSold')) {
            resultSold[symbolBase + 'VolumeSold'] += lots * 100.000
        }
        else {
            resultSold[symbolBase + 'VolumeSold'] = lots * 100.000
        }
      }
  }
}
```